# Bootstrap 3.0 inline headings tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following piece of code:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <h2 class="pull-left">Heading</h2>
                <h4>Second Heading</h4>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The goal is to have both the `<h2>` and the `<h4>` next to each other, on the same base line. At this point the `<h4>` element is way above the line.

I've tried to put this into *spans*, and other 'tricks' like `vertical-align: bottom`.
For some reason I just simply cannot get this on the same line, and same 'line-height like this:

> Heading **Second Heading**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was going to just work off the first answer, but here is a more complete answer:

http://bootply.com/79703

The HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="well inline-headers">
      <h2>heading</h2>
      <h4>second heading</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.inline-headers h2, .inline-headers h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Two things are happening here. First, we dropped some unnecessary floats on the headings, as well as the completely unnecessary clearfix div. For future reference, you do not need to attach a clearfix to a separate div.

Second, I would suggest creating a new class, instead of overriding the behavior of the well class as MasterPoint's example states, in case you ever want the well to style H2s and H4s normally.

Comment: Yes, this did the trick. Apparently the clearfix and float's are not needed. Your HTML made this now clear for me.

Answer (score 23):

Surprised its not been mentioned but another way would be to use the heading classes.

```
<span class="h2 pull-left">heading</span>
<span class="h4">second heading</span>
```

See the less file where they [typography styles](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/type.less) are applied, everything you need apart from the display:block

Comment: This works great for matching styles, but, depending on your needs, the accepted answer is sementically correct.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it's using the oob bootstrap classes

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap has built-in support for secondary headings with `<small>`.

```
<h3>h3. Bootstrap heading <small>Secondary text</small></h3>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-headings

Answer (score 0):

Check the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/VccZ6/2/

you have wrong float in your h2 and here is a rest of css which is needed.

```
.well h2, .well h4 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    line-height: 100%;
}
```

Updated...

...this, will do the job.

Comment: Ive tried that without success. Even when I added a margin:0px; and a padding:0px; While adding those 0 margin/padding it came a bit closer to my point. Also tried to change baseline to bottom.