# display: inline, inline-block and block - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display `h4` and `h5` with `display: inline` and also I want to do this using pure bootstrap classes.

I can do this but using a dirty way like

```
<h4 class="visible-xs-inline visible-sm-inline visible-md-inline visible-lg-inline ">This is inline h4</h4>
<h5 class="visible-xs-inline visible-sm-inline visible-md-inline visible-lg-inline ">This is inline h5</h5>
```

This is *not a legitimate* way according to me. I want a clean way for `inline`, `inline-block` and `block`... How can I do this using bootstrap classes ?

Comment: just create your own stylesheet and set h4 and h5 to display: inline this will over write bootstrap default behavior

Comment: I know I can do this ... but I want to know is there any existing classes for these ??

Comment: I believe not without editing the srouce or overriding them with a separate stylesheet, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684526/bootstrap-3-0-inline-headings-tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use .pull-left to float h4 and h5 inside a div with .clearfix class for clearing.